# Как высчитать резкость в изображени (Opencv)

Tags: opencv

Нужно высчитать резкость в изображении. Знаю что для этого нужно использовать Sobel. А вот как дальше? Есть идея: посчитать колличесво беллых пикселей в изображении после того, как изображение пройдет через Sobel. Но насколько это потимальная идея? Посоветуйте пожалуйста как лучше сделать.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, нужно вести подсчёт не количества пикселей на градиенте изображения, а сумму значений амплитуды в частотном диапазоне. Можно использовать оператор Собеля:

```
cv::Mat grd_x_mat, grd_y_mat, grd_mat;
cv::Sobel(src_mat, grd_x_mat, 1, 0, 3, CV_16S /*для точности: CV_32F*/);
cv::Sobel(src_mat, grd_y_mat, 0, 1, 3, CV_16S /*аналогично*/);
cv::magnitude(grd_x_mat, grd_y_mat, grd_mat);
double level = cv::sum(grd_mat)[0];
```

... или Лапласа (оператор Собеля будет вызван прозрачно):

```
cv::Laplacian(src_mat, grd_mat, CV_16S, 3);
double level = cv::sum(grd_mat)[0];
```

Можно также просто ограничиться морфологической операцией, заключающейся в вычислении разности между "расширенной" (dilate) и "суженной" (erode) копиями одного и того же изображения:

```
cv::morphologyEx(src_mat, grd_mat, cv::MORPH_GRADIENT
   , cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT,cv::Size(3,3)));
double level = cv::sum(grd_mat)[0];
```

Но конечно это всё сугубо субъективно в отношении каждого конкретного изображения, поскольку даже просто изменив контрастность, мы получим и иные значения градиента.